# well-posedness of heat equation with Neumann BC and periodic data

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

On a domain $\Omega$ with $f \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ such that $f(0) = f(T)$, consider
$$u_t - \Delta u = f\quad\text{on $\Omega$}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0\quad\text{on $\partial\Omega$}$$
$$u(0) = u(T)$$

Is there any well-posedness result in Sobolev/Bochner spaces for this problem?

I am wondering whether the associated bilinear form $b(u,v)$ (in this case $b(u,v) = \int \nabla u \nabla v$) has to be coercive in the stronger sense $b(v,v) \geq C|v|_{V}$ rather than just $b(v,v) + A|v|_H \geq C|v|_V$ (here $V=H^1$ and $H=L^2$).

Comment: Typically you will need to know something about the smoothness of the boundary of your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look [here](http://netlizama.usach.cl/Keyantuo-Lizama%28JEE-Final%29%282006%29.pdf). their setting is more abstract, but your specific equation should be just a special case of it.

Comment: The link in the post seems to be dead. I will add at least in a comment a [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20150414164229/http://netlizama.usach.cl/Keyantuo-Lizama(JEE-Final)(2006).pdf) and I'll mention that the paper is Valentin KeyantuoCarlos Lizama: *[Mild Well-posedness of Abstract Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7643-7794-6_24)*.